# Is it possible to set environment variables for exactly one test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Given something like this:

```
it('uses env variables correctly', function(done) {
    assert.equal(process.env.x * process.env.y, 10);
});
```

I would like to set the `x` and `y` environment variable for this one test only. Is that possible?

Comment: I do not think that is possible in Node, you could normally do a beforeTest set of variables through node by accessing the `x` and `y` of the process.env global variable, but that is a bad practice. 

A question though, why would you test NodeJs functionality? Perhaps you should rethink the necessity of this test.

Answer (score 29):

Here is the most common approach:

```
describe('env', function () {
  var env;

  // mocking an environment
  before(function () {
    env = process.env;
    process.env = { x: 2, y: 5 };
  });

  // running tests
  it('uses env variables correctly', function (done) {
    assert.equal(process.env.x * process.env.y, 10);
    done();
  });

  // restoring everything back
  after(function () {
    process.env = env;
  });
});
```

Comment: In my case I could not monkey patch the entire `.env`. Due to marshaling of the object and that dependent library already referenced env; I had to modify the key and value directly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very common pattern (as answered by [Leonid Beschastny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202461/leonid-beschastny)).

```
describe('env', function () {
  let envCache

  // mocking an environment
  before(() => {
    envCache = process.env;
  })

  // running tests
  it('reads env variables correctly', () => {
    process.env.x = 2
    process.env.y = 5

    assert.equal(process.env.x * process.env.y, 10)
  })

  // process.env is not just a plain object
  it('should convert undefined to a string', () => {
    process.env.UNDEF = undefined

    assert.equal(process.env.UNDEF, 'undefined')
  })

  // Trying to restore everything back
  after(() => {
    process.env = env
  })
})
```

There is a problem here, however. `process.env` is *not* a normal object, and you are replacing it with a normal object. If the second test is run in isolation, it will pass, as that is how `process.env` is supposed to work. If instead we run the whole test suite, *the second test will fail*!

Setting up your tests like that will cause different behaviors based on how you run the test. This is a *very* bad thing.

Instead you should use `delete` to clear the values, and then reassign them like so:

```
describe('env', function () {
  let envCache

  // mocking an environment
  before(() => {
    envCache = process.env;
  })

  // running tests
  it('reads env variables correctly', () => {
    process.env.x = 2
    process.env.y = 5

    assert.equal(process.env.x * process.env.y, 10)
  })

  // process.env is not just a plain object
  it('should convert undefined to a string', () => {
    process.env.UNDEF = undefined

    assert.equal(process.env.UNDEF, 'undefined')
  })

  // Trying to restore everything back
  after(() => {
    Object.keys(process.env).forEach((key) => { delete process.env[key] })
    Object.entries(envCache).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
      if (key !== undefined) {
        process.env[key] = value
      }
    })
  })
})
```

This will keep the behavior more consistent, in case someone forgets that you shouldn't assign a key of `process.env` to be undefined instead of deleting them.

Comment: I don't understand why running the whole test suite causes the second test to fail?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked better for me.

In this case you'll not need to re-define the other environment variables that you may need in your test.

```
describe('fake env', () => {
  let envOrig;
  before(() => {
    envOrig = JSON.stringify(process.env);
    process.env.test = 'info';
  });

  after(() => {
    process.env = JSON.parse(envOrig);
  })

  it('check fake env', () => {
    expect(process.env.test).to.equal('info');
  })
});

describe('real env', () => {
  it('check real env', () => {
    expect(process.env.test).to.be.undefined;
  })
});
```